# Select from two table than order it

Tags: php, mysql

I have 4 table, default_table, table_a, table_b, table_c, each have two columns,
I want to select `name` and `id` from all table then sort it,
I try`"SELECT Name,ID FROM default_table, table_a, table_b, table_c ORDER BY Name"`
but this give me error, so can someone help me with this problem, i need code in sql or php, or even javascript if it can

Comment: Javascript is a client side technology and therefore can't really interact with mysql directly. what's the error you're getting as that will help us?

Comment: `SELECT Error Name is ambiguos`, something like that

Comment: that's because you have the same column name in more than one table so  the db doesn't know which column you want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `order by` is applied after unioning, you can just do:

```
select id, name from default_table
    union all select id, name from table_a
    union all select id, name from table_b
    union all select id, name from table_c
order by name
```

Your problem is that you're doing a Cartesian product of all the table data so it's can't figure out *which* `id` or `name` you mean. Even if it could, you'd get *way* more rows than you'd expect, due to the multiplicative effect. You want to join the data simply by *adding* all the rows to the output.

---

Explaining the distinction further, let's say you have two tables:

```
table1          table2
======          ======
id     name     id     name
--     ----     --     ------
 1     pax       1     jill
 2     bob       2     debbie
 3     joe
```

The query:

```
select a.id, a.name, b.id, b.name from table1 a, table2 b
```

(the cartesian product) will give you:

```
1 pax 1 jill
1 pax 2 debbie
2 bob 1 jill
2 bob 2 debbie
3 joe 1 jill
3 joe 2 debbie
```

(the row count is the product of the individual row counts) whereas:

```
select id, name from table1
union all
select id, name from table2
```

(the union) will give you:

```
1 pax
2 bob
3 joe
1 jill
2 debbie
```

(the row count is the sum of the individual row counts).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need `UNION` (or `UNION ALL`):

```
SELECT *
FROM
  ( SELECT Name, ID 
    FROM default_table
  UNION ALL
    SELECT Name, ID 
    FROM table_a
  UNION ALL
    SELECT Name, ID 
    FROM table_b
  UNION ALL
    SELECT Name, ID 
    FROM table_c
  ) AS un
ORDER BY Name
```

Comment: No need for a subselect here, by the way.

Comment: @paxdiablo: You are right. I wasn't sure. You can even apply order by to the sub-selects and order by to the union if you enclose the subselects in parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
SELECT 
    t1.name AS t1_name, t1.id AS t1_id, 
    t2.name AS t2_name, t2.id AS t2_id, 
    t3.name AS t3_name, t3.id AS t3_id, 
    t4.name AS t4_name, t4.id AS t4_id
FROM 
    default_table AS t1,
    table_a AS t2,
    table_b AS t3,
    table_c AS t4
ORDER BY t1.name
```

Comment: You are not joining the tables, this will generate the cross-product.